# How to fix SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module?

Tags: typescript, express, ts-node

I am new to all of this, and I'm trying to add Node + Typescript backend to my Angular project. But after importing express I always get the error.

```
[ERROR] SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "ts-node-dev server.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.6",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNEXT",                                
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "strict": false, 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true,                          
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        
  }
}
```

#### server.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.listen(4201, '127.0.0.', function() {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 4201');
});
```

I have looked this up and the most common solution was to add "type": "module" to package.json which I did. I also know that this works only from Node 13 and further, and I have Node: 14.15.5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice to import the node modules is by using require(). You can import built-in core node modules, npm modules as well as local modules using require() function. In your case, use `const express = require( "express" )` instead of `import * as express from 'express'` and remove "type":"module" from your package.json. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Though I've tried something similar before I must have made a mistake before.

Comment: You're welcome. Just make sure to import the modules using require from next time.

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again but how do I correctly export? `export {app as routes};` This is probably wrong, just as my imports were.

Comment: Hi again, no problem, always open to help. To export, you have to use `module.exports`. For an instance, let's say you have a function like this `const func = () => console.log('hello world')` in file.js. So all you have to do is `module.exports = func` and then again use `require()` to import it anywhere. And let's say you have multiple functions or objects inside a file, then you can do something like this `module.exports={ function1, object1 }`. Let me know if you need more clarity. You can also refer this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/import-and-export-in-node-js/).