# Trying to import csv file data to Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the code below to upload data to Firestore but am getting the error message below:

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

on this line of code:

"import promises from 'fs';"

```
import { promises } from 'fs';
const { readFile } = promises;
import { promisify } from 'util';
const parse = promisify(import('csv-parse'));
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore';

if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  console.error('Please include a path to a csv file');
  process.exit(1);
}

const db = new Firestore();

function writeToFirestore(records) {
  const batchCommits = [];
  let batch = db.batch();
  records.forEach((record, i) => {
    var docRef = db.collection('firebasetest').doc(record.acctid);
    batch.set(docRef, record);
    if ((i + 1) % 500 === 0) {
      console.log(`Writing record ${i + 1}`);
      batchCommits.push(batch.commit());
      batch = db.batch();
    }
  });
  batchCommits.push(batch.commit());
  return Promise.all(batchCommits);
}

async function importCsv(csvFileName) {
  const fileContents = await readFile(csvFileName, 'utf8');
  const records = await parse(fileContents, { columns: true });
  try {
    await writeToFirestore(records);
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  console.log(`Wrote ${records.length} records`);
}

importCsv(process.argv[2]).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Comment: Did you try a web search on that error message? This seems heavily discussed on this site and elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: Hi, Let me know if this [link](https://exerror.com/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-nodejs/) helps you. Also you can try using require instead of import as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67025918/15774177)

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I have been searching for information for this error and following instructions given on this site to correct it.  Thank you for the additional links I will review these.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download and install [Firefoo](https://firefoo.app/).
2. sign in with Google. Right-click your project in the left sidebar and choose Import Collections.
   [image]
3. Click on the Data File field and select your JSON or CSV file.
4. That’s it! Click the Import button.

**Your CSV rows are imported into Firestore and a progress popup opens.**